# how to load a new screen in QML showing a new list based on previous user click input?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

In my application i show a nested list, that shows groups and folders as its children. I have built the functions necesary to generate a new list in the backend in c++ based on which item is clicked by the user.

I allready have the necesary functionality to pass the list to qml through QProperty.

so my question is, how do i previous listviews and show new ones dynamically. Considering it should also be possible to click the button "back", which should load the previous page again showing the groups and the folders.

this is the code i have now, showing the groups and its children(folders)

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
//import ListMode 1.0

Rectangle {
    height: 250
    width: 140
    color: "pink"



    //property var aNum: 0

    Component {
        id: folderDelegate

        Item {
            width: 140
            height: col2.childrenRect.height

            Column {
                id: col2
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right


                Rectangle {
                    height: 20
                    width: parent.width
                    border.color: "black"

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: treemodel.getObject(model.ID + ":" + model.Name)

                    }

                    Text {
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        id: name1
                        text: model.Name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: outer
        model: myModel
        delegate: groupsDelegate
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component {
        id: groupsDelegate

        Item {
            width: 140
            height: col.childrenRect.height

            Column {
                id: col
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right

                Text {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    id: t1
                    font.bold: true
                    font.underline: true
                    font.pointSize: 9
                    text: model.Name
                }

                ListView {
                    id: folderlist
                    model: treemodel.lists[treemodel.modIndex]
                    delegate: folderDelegate
                    contentHeight: contentItem.childrenRect.height
                    height: childrenRect.height
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    clip: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i have been reading documentations and searching forums, but the information is pretty overwhelming. So a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: A `ListView` inside a delegate sounds ugly, a lot. What about a `StackView` with a `ListView` in the first page and a "children elements" `ListView` in the second page? When an element of the first page is clicked the second `ListView` is updated with its children and a transition applys to show that page.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo thnx for answering and sorry for the late reply. Why is it ugly to use a ListView inside a delegate? I have continued using that aproach combined with stackview. The first page shows a set of nested lists and the second page in the stackview also shows a set of nested lists based on what was pressed. The problem is, if i were to use a page for every list, the pages would have quite a bit of depth which is not prefered.. but anyways, i have figured out how to do all this, so this question can be closed

Comment: Delegate should be left as lightweight as possible to improve scrolling. That said, I can see that in a short-numbered list it does not make difference. Many Qt example are based on the approch I'm talking about. But I0m not talking about different lists for each child. Nope. Just one list with different model loaded on demand (aka `onClick`). Anyway, I'm happy you have solved it. :)

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo aaah i see,,, i understand! Maybe i will have to switch aproach soon... the second page holds a list of comments.. which can grow if the user clicks on "show more". Is it possible to have nested lists without using a ListView inside a delegate? Maybe i should make that a question. :D

Comment: You can have a nested model as a back-end code and use different method-fetching-procedures to take the info you are interested on. There's a recent question about that.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo yes i have something like that now, a seperate qml page that holds code for a nested listview. When an item is clicked on the frontpage, certain methods are triggered in c++ that generate data and store it in a QAbstractListModel subclass which is in turn added to a listview in qml through certain methods

Comment: Uhm, it sounds more reasonable now. Well done! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main model is setup for each item to have its own unique ID. So when an item is clicked, i run a function that grabs and stores the item based on the ID + name that was clicked

```
MouseArea {
   anchors.fill: parent

   onClicked :{
     treemodel.getObject(model.ID + ":" + model.Name)
     stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("content/ButtonPage.qml"))     
   }
}
```

next, based on the item that was clicked i have functions that fill different QList items which are loaded into the ButtonPage.qml.

the function in c++ that is invoked is:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void getObject(QString index) {
    clickedItemID = index;
    getClickedItem();
    getFilesByFolder();
}
```

now, i am not sure if this is a good solution. But for me it works. Maybe it will work for someone else too.